# What is for(;;)?

Tags: for-loop

I've been reading some code and saw a for loop with no statements, and I tryed to search what it meant and found nothing (probably because if I type something like "What is for(;;)" in google it just reads as if it was "What is for()"). I don't know if it's just a way to like disable a loop and make it not run (cause I tested it once and the code inside de loop didn't run), though I would think people would just comment or erase the loop, and I'm just curious

Comment: You might want to add a language tag to your question.

Comment: that means an infinite loop same as `while(true)` and it could be language specific

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the only reason I didn't is because I saw it in more than one language, so I assumed it happend in at least more than one language

Comment: Pick a language. It doesn't necessarily mean the same thing in every language where it's valid syntax.

Comment: @chepner I know it doesn't mean the same, and I'm interested in knowing what it does in various languages, like in Mushroomator answer. It's good to know that if I'm using like Javascrip it will work but if I'm using Python it won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite the opposite of not running. It's an infinite loop.

```js
for(;;){
  console.log("test")
}
```

Open an new tab and you press `F12` and then enter the code above in the developer console you will see that `test` gets printed quite often and your browser/ tab will get unresponsive quickly and your PC/ laptop might get louder as the cooler speeds up because the computer is busy looping.

So better quickly kill the tab where you're running it or if you run it in Node kill the process with `Ctrl + C`.

The code above is equivalent to:

```js
while(true){
  console.log("test")
}
```

The above is **JavaScript**, but that would also hold true for **Java**, **C**, **C++**, **C#**. Due to `for(;;)` being incorrect syntax for these languages it will not do anything in **Kotlin**, **GoLang**, **Python**, **Rust**, **Swift** or **Groovy** (and probably many others).

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop looks like this:

```
for (init_statement; condition; iteration_expression) statement
```

This is equivalent to:

```cpp
{
  init_statement ;
  while ( condition ) {
    statement
    iteration_expression ;
  }
}
```

An omitted `condition` is equivalent to `true`.  Omitted `init_statement` or `iteration_expression` is like an empty statement or expression (does nothing).

So, `for(;;) statement` is equivalent to:

```cpp
{
  /* no init_statement */
  while ( true ) {
    statement
    /* no iteration expression */
  }
}
```